# php-angularjs executable phar not working

Tags: php, angularjs, phar

I have my single page application with angularjs and php and after the completion of project I created executable file successfully but it seems not working any more. Here are my php code for creating phar. Please give me some suggestion for this.

create_phar.php

```
$phar = new Phar('crud.phar', 0, 'crud.phar');
$phar->startBuffering();
$phar->buildFromDirectory('crud');
$phar->setStub($phar->createDefaultStub('index.php', 'crud\index.php'));
$phar->compress(Phar::GZ);
$phar->stopBuffering();
```

run_phar.php

```
include 'phar://crud.phar.gz/index.php';
```

Folder Structure of my project

```
-crud
  --index.php
  --css(contains all .css files)
  --js(contains all .js files)
    --Controllers.js
    --Directives.js
    --Services.js
  --img(contains images)
  --partials(contains all html template files)
  --classes(contains php class file and other files)
    --databaseClass.php
    --login.php
    --user.php
    --logout.php
```

AngulaJs is responsible for making ajax call, so if login button is clicked then it will call a `POST` request to `classes/login.php`, and when all the users will be listed after login then it calls a `GET` request to `classes/user.php`, all the response is in JSON. Now suppose I want to run the same project in other system(client) so I need to copy the whole project and paste into the client system, but the client can able to open the `.php` files. So that's why I want to create a executable `.phar` archive so that its not visible to other peoples. So please give me some solution for this.

Thanks, In advance